# A batch to rename

Tags: batch-file, rename

I would like to rename a file as its parent folder example:

```
D:\Books\PDF\medical\001\99.jpg
D:\Books\PDF\medical\002\gg.jpg
```

to be:

```
D:\Books\PDF\medical\001\001.jpg
D:\Books\PDF\medical\002\002.jpg
```

I know this question asked before but I could not understand it.

also if it is possible I would like to put it in `D:\Books\PDF\medical\`

Comment: Is this in windows or what operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to do it:

This is pretty easy:

1) Create a new text file named "myrename.bat" in "D:\Books\PDF\medical\".

2) Paste the following into it:

```
@echo off
pushd %~p1
for %%d in ("%CD%") do set "parentdir=%%~nd"
popd
move /Y %1 D:\Books\PDF\medical\"%parentdir%%~x1" > nul
```

3) From "D:\Books\PDF\medical\", run the batch file with its first argument being the name
of the file to be renamed. For instance, here's what you would do for the file "gg.jpg" in your example:

```
myrename 002\gg.jpg
```

This will rename the file "99.jpg" to "002.jpg" and move it to "D:\Books\PDF\medical\".

### How it works

In batch, `%~p1` returns the relative path of the first argument, *i.e.* it strips the folder. For instance, if you run `myrename Bla\002\gg.jpg`, `%~p1` would be `Bla\002`. `pushd` then steps into this directory.

The `for` loop is supposed to extract the last folder from the current path, given by `%CD%`, and the value of `%CD%` is assigned to `%%d`. The expression `%~nd` is used to discard everything but the name of the last folder, the obtained result being stored in the variable `parentdir`. `popd` then returns to the original directory.

The `move` command both renames the file and moves it. The new filename is the value of `parentdir` and the extension `%~x1`, which is the extension of the original input file.

Hope this helps.